# Spring Integration JMS/IBM MQ: how can I business logic it if not receiving a response

Tags: java, spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

My project is using jms+ibmmq to send a message out. it's working properly, and I'm able to push a message to the outbound queue, and then receive a response from the inbound queue. Recently, a client asks if we can send out an alert email if unable to get a response within like 2 min.  I checked the spring integration messaging related document, seems gatway can implement it? but still can't get an idea how to use it. can someone help me out?

my current xml configuration

```
<integration:service-activator id="serviceActivator1" input-channel="inputChannel"
                               ref="messageProcessService" method="callMsgProcessor"  output-channel="requestChannel" />  

<bean id="ibmConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
            <property name="transportType">
                <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT"/>
            </property>
            <property name="hostName" value="${hostName}"/>
            <property name="queueManager" value="${queue-manager}"/>
            <property name="channel" value="${channel}"/>
            <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="5"/>
</bean>

<bean id="requestQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${request-queue}"/>
    <property name="targetClient">
        <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="request.queue.adapter" connection-factory="ibmConnectionFactory"
                              destination="requestQueue" channel="requestChannel"/>

<integration:channel id="requestChannel"/> 


<bean id="responseQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${response-queue}"/>
</bean>
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="responseJMSAdapater"
                                    destination="responseQueue"
                                    channel="responseChannel"
                                    connection-factory="ibmConnectionFactory"
                                    error-channel="errorChannel"
                                    acknowledge="transacted"                                        
/>
<integration:channel id="responseChannel">
    <integration:queue capacity="500"/>
    <integration:interceptors>
        <integration:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </integration:interceptors>
</integration:channel>
```

if add a gateway, it looks like

```
<integration:gateway id="serviceAdaptedGateway" service-interface="com.mycompany.service.gatewayServiceInterface"
                                                  default-request-channel="requestChannel"
                                                  default-reply-channel="responseChannel"
                                                  default-reply-timeout="120000"/>
```

my question is

1. seems timeout not working, nothing happen even the waiting time exceed the timeout
2. although the gateway provide timeout property, where I can add my business logic like send email alert?

Comment: Is your question about Active MQ or IBM MQ? Your title and first sentence contradict each other.

Comment: Hi @MoragHughson, it's ibm mq

Comment: Please provide a link to the spring documentation that you refer to, so we can read how it should work, and hopefully discover why it doesn't in your case.

Comment: Create a statefull service which has two methods: scheduleMail() and cancelMail(). When sending request also invoke scheduleMail which will compose mail and put it in a scheduler for next two minutes. After receiving response invoke cancelMail() which will remove scheduled mail from a scheduler. Write your own scheduler or use Quartz or something similar if in clustered environment.. You can user correlation id to pair request/response.

Comment: @Talijanac, thank you so much for the solution, it really make sense, I'll try it.